# SQL query ordering in custom order

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a custom ordering need like this:

```
normal ordering  |  custom ordering 
      1          |        7
      2          |        6
      3          |        5
      4          |        4
      5          |        3
      6          |        2
      7          |        8
      .          |        .
      .          |        .
      .          |        .
      .          |        .
      .          |        N
      N          |        1
```

I have thought about using `UNION` to combine 3 different select queries with the help of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. However, I can not do that because `UNION` have to be used **before** `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

How can I make a selection (or selections) to achieve the custom ordering above?

Another workaround might help is just make the **1st record** returned in this select query the last record, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT x
FROM t1
ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN x = 1 THEN 100000001
      WHEN x between 2 and 7 THEN 7 - x
      WHEN x between 8 and ( SELECT max(x) FROM t1 ) - 1 THEN x
      ELSE 100000000 
    END
```

100000000 constans must be greather than N.
Here is a [simple demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b67ee/4)

Comment: Thanks for your aid. IMHO, using the hard-coded "100000001" might cause problem if the records gets larger and larger in the future?

Comment: What about with the DISTINCT query?

Answer (score 2):

Add a New Table `CustomSeq` with two columns, `Value` and `Sequence`. In that table you can store the values and their custom order. then join to that table and order by it's `Sequence` column.