# Custom Order by in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have to do custom order by in my code,

Consider below E.g:

```
class Car(models.Model):    
     type
     brand
```

Whenever I do order by using brand I get below query set

```
cars = ["Benz","BMW","Ford","Honda","Suzuki"]
```

> I need to do order by brand in which "BMW" should always come at last like below queryset,

```
cars = ["Benz","Ford","Honda","Suzuki", "BMW"]
```

Note: I don't want to use/ convert it as list. I need to do some queryset operations (like values_list) on this after order by.

Comment: You'll have to use custom SQL. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18238896/3224008

Comment: What is the logic that puts BMW last? or is it just personal preference?

Comment: Add an extra field in your model as go_last and order by go_last and then brand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do it like here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176471/4971083

It's the solution for ordering your records by specific value in Django.

```
car = Car.objects.filter(product__id=product_id).extra(
        select={'is_top': " brand='BMW'"})
car = car.extra(order_by = ['is_top'])
```